# Return missing number from Array (algorithm)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm working on an algorithm problem (on leetcode) which is asking the following:

Given an array containing `n` distinct numbers taken from `0, 1, 2, ..., n,` find the one that is missing from the array.

For example,
Given `nums = [0, 1, 3]` return `2`.

My current answer is:

```
var missingNumber = function(nums) {
  return nums.filter(function(item, index, arr) {
    return arr[index] - arr[index - 1] > 1;
  }).shift() - 1; 
};
```

However, leetcode is using these two test cases (among some others) which make no sense to me:

Input: `[0]`
Expected: `1`

Input: `[0, 1]`
Expected: `2`

EDIT: also...

Input: `[1]`
Expected: `0`

From what I understand, the algorithm is asking to return a **single** number that is missing from an array, given there is a number that is **actually missing** in the first place. Am I missing something here or are the instructions for this algorithm very unclear?

Comment: Sounds like it wants the next number in the sequence if it gives a properly formatted array

Comment: I think they simply want to count from `0` until `arr.length+1`, and `return` on the first that you don't find in the array where you expected it.

Comment: @IrkenInvader: I see, that would explain the test cases. Although it also expects `[1]` to return `0`. I'll edit my description.

Comment: [1] would return 0 because 0 is missing (it should be the first element)

Comment: That makes more sense. I think that could be explained a bit clearer, but perhaps it's my mistake.

Comment: Yeah, rereading the requirements i'm actually not sure if it should always start at 0 and count up... that seems to be the case from the examples though.  Slightly confusing requirements indeed.

Comment: Are these already sorted.. if sorted do an Array.reduce and check differences if not sort first and do so.

Answer (score 5):

There is a different way to do it using XOR operation. The idea here is that a number XORed with itself will always be 0. We can store XORs of all the numbers from 0 to N in variable `xor1` and XORs of all the numbers of our array in variable `xor2`. The XOR of `xor1` and `xor2` will be the missing number as it will only appear in `xor1` and not in `xor2`.

```
function foo(arr){
        var n = arr.length;
        var xor1 = 0, xor2 = 0;
        for(var i = 0;i <= n;i++)
                xor1 ^= i;
        for(var i = 0;i < n;i++)
                xor2 ^= arr[i];
        return xor1 ^ xor2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The total of the integers from `1..n` is:

[image]

So, the expected total of an array of length `n` with values from `0..n` would be the same. The missing number would be the total minus the sum of the actual values in the array:

```
"use strict";
let missingNumber = function(nums) {
    let n = nums.length;
    let expected = n * (n + 1) / 2;
    let total = nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    return expected - total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would implement it, you can loop until `<=` to the array length so if the passed in array passes the test it will try to look at `nums[nums.length]`  which will be `undefined` and return `i` correctly.  Return 0 if they pass in an empty array.

```
var missingNumber = function(nums){
  for(var i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++){
    if(nums[i] !== i) return i;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear from OP's description that the numbers are required to be in any particular order e.g., given the array `[2, 4, 0, 1, 5]` the answer would be `3`, but I may be misreading it.

Comment: Yeah we weren't sure either!  His test cases seem to be leaning in the always start at 0 and count up direction.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the test cases aren't made public until you start submitting code but it appears that the array will be given in order by default. Thank you, everyone!

Comment: Actually, now it is throwing unordered arrays. All things considered, the description is not properly explaining the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `indexOf()` method. It returns `-1` if the item is not found.

```
nums = [0, 1, 3];
var missingNumber = function(nums){
  for(i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++){
    if(nums.indexOf(i) < 0 ) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: good idea for starters but instead the check should be done like `if (i !== nums[i]) return i` hence o(n)

Comment: @David Conrad True.. has to sort them first and i guess still will be faster than indexOf method which i think must be o(n^2 / 2) by the way since indexOf won't continue all the way to the end once it finds it's target. It might be safe to assume indexOf running half of the array per search in average.

Comment: @Redu constant factors are ignored in big-O analysis, though.